# Facebook tab app - alternative landing page for "liked" users

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have developed one Facebook Application.
In facebook, page tab url I have specified a landing url, it is landing safely no issues.
Now I want if I click on like button, it should  call another landing page.

What can be best solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will have to do is read the `signed_request` passed to your tab application.

The `signed_request` will contain information on whether or not the current user "liked" the page that the app is on.  Once you know if the user "liked" the page or not, in the even that s/he has already liked the page, you can redirect them to whatever URL you wish.

I see you have specified `asp.net` of which I have no knowledge, but I *can* tell you that the `signed_request` is passed to your application as a POST request.  From there you need to [parse the signed request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560024/asp-net-facebook-api-reading-a-signed-request-only-given-in-docs-as-php) and then you can read it's contents.

Here is a simple JavaScript redirect (in PHP) -

```
echo "<script language=javascript>";
echo "window.location.href ='".$url."';";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.
Assume that i have got liked value.
Now how can i change landing URL.

My Current Default URL is http://abc.com/A.aspx
Now i want to change it to http://abc.com/B.aspx
I am deadly stuck here.

Comment: You just need to execute a redirect.  I've added one method (with JavaScript) to my answer... I'm sure you can translate that from PHP to `asp`...

Comment: You can not change the landing URL... there is only one landing URL for a page tab application.  You'll have to simulate a different landing page by means of the redirect...

Comment: I tried top.location.href but it is opening in complete window not inside canvas page.

Comment: Can you please explain it more ??
"You'll have to simulate a different landing page by means of the redirect..."

Comment: Oh.. you want it to be a different **internal** landing page... ok ok... so just use `location.href` or `window.location.href`...

Comment: Its coming in complete window not inside internal window.